# jbpm could not find work item handler for human task

Tags: jbpm

I searched stackoverflow, but couldn't find answer.

I used eclipse to debug process with run time of jbpm 7.9(there is one user task in bpmn) and hit error of "could not find work item handler for human task".

I tried to add:

```
ksession.getWorkItemManager().registerWorkItemHandler("Human Task",new ServiceTaskHandler());
```

this time I got error of `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

two questions:

1. why jbpm doesn't have a default work item handler for human task? (btw, I can run process in kie workbench without any issues).
2. Is ServiceTaskHandler the correct handler for Human task/user task?

Answer (score 0):

In jBPM 7 release you dont need to register WorkItemHandler for HumanTask operation. Its already available in session.